# indexing through values of a nested list using mapply

Tags: r, mapply

I have a list of lists, with each sub-list containing 3 values.  My goal is to cycle through every value of this nested list in a systematic way (i.e. start with list 1, go through all 3 values, go to list 2, and so on), applying a function to each.  But my function hits missing values and breaks and I've traced the problem to the indexing itself, which doesn't behave in the way I am expecting.  The lists are constructed as:

```
pop <- 1:100
treat.temp <- NULL
treat <- NULL

## Generate 5 samples of pop
for (i in 1:5){
    treat.temp <- sample(pop, 3)
    treat[[i]] <- treat.temp
}

## Create a list with which to index mapply
iterations <- (1:5)
```

Illustrative function and results.

```
test.function <- function(j, k){
  for (n in 1:3){
    print(k[[n]][j])
  }
}

results <- mapply(test.function, iterations, treat)

[1] 61
[1] 63
[1] 73
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
[1] NA
<snipped>
```

For the first cycle through 'j', this works.  But after that it throws NAs.  But if I do it manually, it returns the values I would expect.

```
> print(treat[[1]][1])
[1] 61
> print(treat[[1]][2])
[1] 63
> print(treat[[1]][3])
[1] 73
> print(treat[[2]][1])
[1] 59
> print(treat[[2]][2])
[1] 6
> print(treat[[2]][3])
[1] 75
<snipped>
```

I'm sure this is a basic question, but I can't seem to find the right search terms to find an answer here or on Google.  Thanks in advance!

**Edited to Add:** MrFlick's answer works well for my problem.  I have multiple list inputs (hence mapply) in my actual use.  A more detailed example, with a few notes.

```
pop <- 1:100
years <- seq.int(2000, 2014, 1)

treat.temp <- NULL
treat <- NULL
year.temp <- NULL
year <- NULL

## Generate 5 samples of treated states, control states and treatment years 
for (i in 1:5){
  treat.temp <- sample(pop, 20)
  treat[[i]] <- treat.temp

  year.temp <- sample(years, 1)
  year[[i]] <- year.temp
}

## Create a list with which to index mapply
iterations <- (1:5)

## Define function 
test.function <- function(j, k, l){
  for (n in 1:3){

    ## Cycles treat through each value of jXn
    print(k[n])
    ## Holds treat (k) fixed for each 3 cycle set of n (using first value in each treat sub-list); cycles through sub-lists as j changes
    print(k[1])
    ## Same as above, but with 2nd value in each sub-list of treat
    print(k[2])
    ## Holds year (l) fixed for each 3 cycle set of n, cycling through values of year each time j changes
    print(l[1])
    ## Functionally equivalent to
    print(l)
  }
}

results <- mapply(test.function, iterations, treat, year)
```

Comment: Your example set-up is a list of vectors, in which case it seems straightforward to apply some function to every value in each vector using `lapply` - as in, `lapply(treat, function(x) x/2)` if you just wanted to divide everything by 2.  Could you clarify your problem a bit more?

Comment: I think you're right (as is MrFlick below) regarding lapply in my example.  I've added a more detailed example for posterity.  I use mapply because I have multiple input lists and some need to be cycled with j but stay fixed over all iterations of n, while others need to cycle with both j and n.  It's possible lapply can handle that, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you might be misunderstanding how `mapply` works. The function will loop through both of the iterations you pass as parameters, which means `treat` will also be subset each iteration. Essentially, the functions being called are

```
test.function(iterations[1], treat[[1]])
test.function(iterations[2], treat[[2]])
test.function(iterations[3], treat[[3]])
...
```

and you seem to treat the `k` variable as if it were the entire list. Also, you have your indexes backwards as well. But just to get your test working, you can do

```
test.function <- function(j, k){
  for (n in 1:3) print(k[n]) 
}

results <- mapply(test.function, iterations, treat)
```

but this isn't really a super awesome way to iterate a list. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you explain why it's suboptimal to iterate through a list this way?

Comment: If you just wanted those values in that order you could just do `unlist(treat)`. There's nothing super wrong with doing it that way, it just seems like it may be easier to an `lapply` or something on the list itself. It depends on what you are doing with the values I guess.